# How can I override the flex-xs breakpoint when printing?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, sass

I have a row of checkboxes, that when the screen size is small enough (less than 600px), collapse into columns.

This is fine, but now when I attempt to print this document, the mobile breakpoints activate, and  stack up in columns, rather than in rows that I want them in.

Here is the min example of the html I have.

```
<div id="printCheckbox" flex="100" layout="row" layout-xs="column" layout-wrap>
    <div flex="33" flex-xs="100" >
        <md-checkbox>1</md-checkbox>
    </div>
    <div flex="33" flex-xs="100" >
        <md-checkbox>2</md-checkbox>
    </div>
    <div flex="33" flex-xs="100" >
        <md-checkbox>3</md-checkbox>
    </div>
    <div flex="33" flex-xs="100" >
        <md-checkbox>4</md-checkbox>
    </div>
    <div flex="33" flex-xs="100" >
        <md-checkbox>5</md-checkbox>
    </div>
    <div flex="33" flex-xs="100" >
        <md-checkbox>6</md-checkbox>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can obviously remove the mobile support to have the print view function correctly, however I am wondering if I can override the flex-xs values in css.

Here is what I am attempting to do in css

```
@media only print {
    #printCheckbox{
        [flex-xs="100"] {
        // Make them 33?
        }
    }
}
```

So is it possible to supply a different value to the flex-xs in css? Or disable the mobile breakpoints completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't really do what I wanted to, but I found a workaround myself.

I made my CSS this for the parent container of the checkboxes

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .printCheckBoxContainer{
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .printCheckBox{
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-basis: 100%;
    }
}

@media only print {
    .printCheckBoxContainer{
        align-items: center;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-direction: row;
    }
    .printCheckBox{
        align-self: center;
        flex-basis: 33%;
    }
```

And then changed my HTML to look like

```
<div class="printCheckBoxContainer" class="verify-identity" flex="100" layout="row" layout-wrap>
    <div class="printCheckBox" flex="33">
        <md-checkbox></md-checkbox>
    </div>
    <div class="printCheckBox" flex="33">
        <md-checkbox></md-checkbox>
    </div>
    <div class="printCheckBox" flex="33">
        <md-checkbox></md-checkbox>
    </div>
    <div class="printCheckBox" flex="33">
        <md-checkbox></md-checkbox>
    </div>
    <div class="printCheckBox" flex="33">
        <md-checkbox></md-checkbox>
    </div>
    <div class="printCheckBox" flex="33">
        <md-checkbox></md-checkbox>
    </div>
</div>
```

So I kept the default breakpoints, then just specified the `flex-basis` in css based on the media queries. Basic stuff, but it works!

Unless I get a better answer within a couple of days, I will accept my own answer.